# Procedure with VARRAY created with compilation errors

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I am trying to create a procedure which will accept a `VARRAY` as an argument and will delete some records from the table. Below are the steps I followed:

**Step1**

Created the `VARRAY` inside a package:

```
create or replace package del_emp is
type rec_del_emp is varray(10) of NUMBER;
end del_emp;
```

**Step 2:**

Created the procedure:

```
create or replace procedure f_del_emp(v_emp del_emp.rec_del_emp%type) is
begin
for i in 1 .. v_emp.count
loop
    delete from emp where emp_id = v_emp(i);
    dbms_output.put_line('Deleted Id: ' || v_emp(i));
end loop;
commit;
end f_del_emp;
```

This procedure is getting created with compilation errors.

I tried checking what the error is using this:

```
select * from SYS.USER_ERRORS 
where NAME = 'f_del_emp' 
and type = 'PROCEDURE';
```

But it is giving: **no rows selected**

I have two questions on this:

1) How to check the errors while creating a Proc / Function? Have I used the correct query for checking the errors? (Need to know this so that every time I get an error, I don't need someone over here to check the same on my behalf)

2) Where lies the error in the above Procedure?

Kindly let me know on these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object names are case-insensitive by default, but are stored in upper-case in the data dictionary; so your query needs to be:

```
select * from SYS.USER_ERRORS 
where name = 'F_DEL_EMP' 
and type = 'PROCEDURE';
```

(Though using `f_` as a prefix for a procedure, rather than a function, seems a bit odd).

You can also do `show errors` if you're creating it in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer.

As for what is wrong in your procedure, I can see two problems immediately. `rec_del_emp` is already a type, so you don't need the `%type` in the parameter declaration. And you have spaces in the `for ... loop` construct, which I think causes an error but can't check right now:

```
create or replace procedure f_del_emp(v_emp del_emp.rec_del_emp) is
begin
for i in 1..v_emp.count
loop
...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
create or replace package del_emp is
type rec_del_emp is varray(10) of NUMBER;
end del_emp;
-- PACKAGE DEL_EMP compiled

create or replace procedure f_del_emp(v_emp del_emp.rec_del_emp%type) is
begin
for i in 1 .. v_emp.count
loop
    delete from emp where emp_id = v_emp(i);
    dbms_output.put_line('Deleted Id: ' || v_emp(i));
end loop;
commit;
end f_del_emp;
/*
PROCEDURE F_DEL_EMP compiled
Errors: check compiler log
*/

SHOW ERRORS;
/*
1/27           PLS-00206: %TYPE must be applied to a variable, column, field or attribute, not to "DEL_EMP.REC_DEL_EMP"
0/0            PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
*/

create or replace procedure f_del_emp(v_emp del_emp.rec_del_emp) is
begin
    for i in 1 .. v_emp.count
    loop
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'delete from emp where emp_id = ' || v_emp(i);
        dbms_output.put_line('Deleted Id: ' || v_emp(i));
    end loop;

    commit;
end f_del_emp;
-- PROCEDURE F_DEL_EMP compiled
```

Comment: Hi, you seem to be doing really well at answering but _just_ posting code isn't necessarily the best thing to do. If you don't explain what's happening and why then your answer is a lot less useful for the future.

Comment: @Ben: Nothing will describe it as well as the documentation. In the future I will try to post links to the proper sections. Thank you for the hint! Cheers!

Comment: No problem @the_slk and thank you for taking my comment the "right" way. Take a look at the top Oracle answerer's, which include Alex who also answered this question. The majority of their answers are text rather than code. You seem to be really up on the code aspect and it'd be great if we gained another person who's also able to explain why things are going wrong.